# how to make live streaming video from mobile to a page on website

Tags: android, streaming, live-streaming

i need help please,i want to make android app that make live streaming video from mobile to a page on  website to transfer events directly to the viewer in an emergency, like  [IP Webcam app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en) or [twitcasting live app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sidefeed.TCLive&hl=en) how can i make this?!!

Answer (score 1):

check the link below this will help you.
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/

Comment: i use this tutorial,but  didn't work when i change the URL to my PC IP and there's a condition that PC and mobile must be in same network and i don't need this

Comment: @AmalKronz The PC and the mobile definitely should not need to be in the same network - that is one of the key characteristics of this type of solution. Maybe you can provide a bit more detail on what did not work.

Comment: i change the url in android part and web part to my PC ip but i don't know what port no to add this is the URL that i add  "rtsp://192.168.1.107:8088/live/android_test " i will edit question with the error appeared